# Multistage build caching with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We use docker in production and in CI to build a set of images.
I found that by using multistage builds and alpine, I get drastically smaller images, which is great.
However since I started using multistage builds, the caching seems broken.
I used to pull a set of images from our local docker registry which helped with most of the cache and then I would push the result back if the build worked.
With multistage builds, the build stage is not cached.

I read this article that seem to solve the issue: https://dev.to/pst418/speed-up-multi-stage-docker-builds-in-ci-cd-with-buildkit-s-registry-cache-11gi

The only issue is that we build our images with docker compose. Is there perhaps a way to enable this buildkit remote caching mechanism when using docker compose?